# Error while changing connection string dynamically

Tags: c#

I am using ADO.net and my requirement is to change server dynamically based on some condition.
So in my web.config I have saved 2 connections as below. One names REMOTE and DBCS

```
<add name="REMOTE" connectionString="Server=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=0" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<add name="DBCS" connectionString="Server=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=0" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And below is the if condition that will change the server. 
I want to use the same ***`con`*** variable throughout the code.

```
if (some condition)
{
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["REMOTE"].ConnectionString;
con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

But while reassigning the new connectionstring to ***`con`*** variable, I am getting error.
Error:

```
Cannot assign to 'con' because it is a 'using variable'
```

As I am new to C#, I am having difficult handling this situation.

Comment: You (correctly) have the `con` instance being created in a `using` block. Pass the correct connection string at the time you *create* the `SqlConnection` instance, do not reassign after it is created.

Comment: Just as a heads up, since you're using the `providerName` of the connection string if you ever want to dynamically switch between two different database types, check into `System.Data.Common` and `DbProviderFactory`, it's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You (correctly) have the con instance being created in a using block. Pass the correct connection string at the time you create the SqlConnection instance, do not reassign after it is created

```
string connectionString = (some condition)
    ? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["REMOTE"].ConnectionString
    : ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   // code using your SqlConnection instance
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a [`using` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) and try to assign a new value within that block, which is not allowed.

The documentation states:

> Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.